# Update all jstree node ids in db on any change

Tags: jstree, jstree-dnd

I tried select_node, activate_node, open_node events and all these events update the corresponding node id in db when they are triggered. 
Scenario:
If a node has many nested child nodes and if I move this parent node into another sibling node, the child nodes id may change in the DOM and i cant update those nodes id into db currently. Thus creating data error. 
How can I avoid this kind of data error in jstree, when persisting node ids to db.
I really appreciate your help. Thank you,